# How to create command for a box where text inside the box can automatically adjust?

Tags: errors, boxes

I have a problem on how I can make my command right. I created a box where the text will be inside it when used but something went wrong when I prolong the text it turn out like this:

### Code:

```
\newcommand{\casebox}[1]{%
\framebox[.5\textwidth][t]{#1}
}
```

[image]

I hope I can make something like this by my command:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have a box with a specified fixed width and have the text wrap inside that box? Or do you want a box that stretches to fit the width of the text you write?

Comment: May I ask why did you unaccept the answer? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: i feel sorry to accept the  answer thoroughly. The thing is, it succesfully compiled but the error is the same when i replace `\lipsum[2]` to \text here text here text here[2]`.. :(

Comment: @Mohan: I would prefer the second option---> box which stretches to fit the width of the text I write.

Comment: @kayla: then I see that your question has been answered below.

Comment: Don't write `\text here text here text here[2]`. Write `text here text here text here`. The backslash indicates that `\lipsum` is a command and the `[2]` is an argument to that command. YOu don't need either of them.

Comment: @kayla as I explained you, there's nothing wrong with my code and it works as expected; you had a syntax error in your replacement text.

Comment: it works now! :) But why is it when i write this continous word `hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh` the output is no longer the same?

Comment: @kayla because that's not a "real" word, so LaTeX's algorithm for hyphenation  can't find a place to break it appropriately.

Comment: Related Question: [mdframed: size frame to content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88634/mdframed-size-frame-to-content).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible solution using the [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\mybox[2][\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{%
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{#1}
#2
\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\mybox{test}

\noindent\mybox{some longer text}

\noindent\mybox{text here text here text here text here text here}

\noindent\mybox{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If my command is always meant to start and end its own paragraph, then the definition can be changed to something like

```
\newcommand\mybox[2][\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{%
\par\noindent\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{#1}
#2
\end{varwidth}}\par}
```

and then one can simply say

```
\mybox{text text text text text}
```

Comment: I can still encounter the same problem. When I replace the command `\noindent\mybox{\lipsum[2]}` to `\noindent\mybox{text here text here text here text here text here[2}}` Still the same output.. some text are outside the box.

Comment: @kayla `\noindent\mybox{text here text here text here text here text here[2}}` has a syntax error; there's an additional brace at the end. Try `\noindent\mybox{text here text here text here text here text here[2]}`

Comment: i already compiled this `\noindent\mybox{text here text here text here text here text here[2]}` and it do gave me no error. But, the output is the same. Half of the text is outside the box. What should i do? the argument `[2]` can visibly seen at the end of the text.

Comment: @kayla if you don't need `[2]`, then don't write it; I used it because it was part of the `\lipsum` command to automatically generate text; `\lipsum[2]` means the second text paragraph. You don't really need this; use simply `\noindent\mybox{text text text text text text text text text text}`.

Comment: @kayla please see my updated answer; there you can see that the code works as expected with your text.

Answer (score 6):

If you are satisfied with a plain box then this is probably not the solution for you.  To illustrate that the basic case works:

[image]

But of course, being a `tikz` solution you can style the boxes.  Here are just a few of the many options that are avilaable:

[image]

Furthermore, by adding the option `text width=\linewidth`, you can chose to have the box take up the full `\linewidth`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\LengthOfText}
\newlength{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth}
\newlength{\TextWidth}
\newcommand{\Boxed}[2][]{%
    % #1 = box draw/fill options
    % #2 = text
    \settowidth{\LengthOfText}{\mbox{#2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth}
        {\LengthOfText-\linewidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\TextWidth}{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth > 0pt ? \linewidth : \LengthOfText}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
            \node [, text width=\TextWidth, #1] (Origin) {#2};
            \draw [thick, draw=black, #1] 
                (Origin.south west) rectangle (Origin.north east) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\noindent\Boxed{test}\par\medskip\noindent
\noindent\Boxed{some longer text}\par\medskip\noindent
\noindent\Boxed{text here text here text here text here text here}\par\medskip\noindent
\noindent\Boxed{\lipsum[2]}

\bigskip\noindent
\Boxed[red]{test}\par\medskip\noindent
\Boxed[dashed]{text here text here text here text here text here}\par\medskip\noindent
\Boxed[fill=yellow!20, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1]{\lipsum[2]}

\bigskip\noindent
\Boxed[blue, text width=\linewidth]{test}\par\medskip\noindent
\Boxed[draw=brown, text width=\linewidth]{text here text here text here text here text here}\par\medskip\noindent
\end{document}
```