# mdframed: size frame to content

Tags: mdframed

Consider this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[innerrightmargin=0pt]
TEXT\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

This produces a frame that is much wider than its content:

[image]

I know this is not a bug: the `mdframed` documentation mentions a `userdefinedwidth` parameter that defaults to `\linewidth`. But how can I get a `mdframed` frame that has the same width as its content?

(What I actually need is a box with rounded corners and shading options; breaking over multiple pages isn't necessary. `mdframed` seemed like the easiest way to get the box, but if it's too much hassle to make it size to content, it would be useful to know so I can try pure `tikz`.)

Comment: If you ask TeX to break the lines then the size of the content _is_ `\linewidth` even if some of the content is white. If you just want a box of natural size then `\fbox{TEXT}` would work, or others will show you fancy Tikz Boxes:-)

Comment: Thanks -- I got decent results with pure `tikz`. (`draw=black!30, fill=gray!4, inner sep = 3mm, outer sep = 3mm, rounded corners=5mm`)

Comment: Feel free to "self answer" to round off the question. (Tikz is far too modern for me:-)

Comment: Possible Duplicate/Related Questions: [A \boxed alternative with nicer spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35217/a-boxed-alternative-with-nicer-spacing), [A \boxed alternative with minimal spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing).

Comment: Also related: [How to create command for a box where text inside the box can automatically adjust?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84074/how-to-create-command-for-a-box-where-text-inside-the-box-can-automatically-adju).

Comment: also related: [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just creating a command using a [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) `node`, something like

```
\newcommand{\myboxedtext}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=orange,rounded corners]{%
            \tikz[baseline=-0.6ex] \node [#1,rounded corners]{#2};}%
```

This has an optional argument, which can be used as demonstrated in the following MWE.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myboxedtext}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=orange,rounded corners]{%
        \tikz[baseline=-0.6ex] \node [#1,rounded corners]{#2};}%

\begin{document}
\myboxedtext{boxed text here}
\lipsum[1]

\myboxedtext[fill=red,text=yellow]{boxed text here}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `at (0,0)`?

Comment: @Mohan good point, it is redundant :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution that uses [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth)  and [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)  packages.  First the `\BODY` of the environment is saved in a `\usebox` using the `varwidth` environment and then its width is measured to specify the `\userdefinewidth` of the `mdframed` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins. It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}%
\NewEnviron{MyMdframed}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        backgroundcolor=lightgray, 
        shadow=true, 
        shadowsize=4pt,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyMdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!20]
    Sample
\end{MyMdframed}
\begin{MyMdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!20]
    Somewhat longer text.
\end{MyMdframed}
\begin{MyMdframed}[backgroundcolor=orange!20]
    Much longer text that takes up more than one line. 
    This should span across the entire width of the page and continue on to the next line.
\end{MyMdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution, it could very well be included in the mdframed package itself as an alternative box.

Answer (score 1):

An example with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) was missing.

By default, regular `tcolorbox` uses `\linewidth` as box width, but the package also provide `\tcbox` command which adjust box size to its contents. Almost all `tcolorbox` options can be applied to `\tcbox`.

Next code shows how to declare `\mybox` command based on `\tcbox`. It has one mandatory option which help to change default options and one optional parameter to change default background and frame color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[2][red]{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, colback=#1!10!white, colframe=#1!50!black, boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,boxrule=1pt,#2}

\begin{document}

\mybox{}{Default box} \lipsum[4]

\mybox[green]{}{Default with different background}
\lipsum[4]

\mybox{colupper=red!30!black,boxrule=2pt}{Non default box}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think cmhughes is on the right track, but would rather have `tikz` do the work of aligning the baselines:

```
\newcommand{\myboxedtext}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=white,rounded corners]{%
            \tikz[baseline] \node [#1,rounded corners,anchor=text]{#2};}%
```