# How to set width of mdframed?

Tags: mdframed

I am new to latex i want to set a width and height of the `mdframed`. can any one help me to achieve this task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newtheorem{mdtheorem}{Theorem}
 \newenvironment{theorem}%
 {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{mdtheorem}}%
 {\end{mdtheorem}\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Sample
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

1. My current output is ,
   [image]
2. My expected output is

[image]

Comment: "My expected output" means that the width of the frame should adapt automatically to the contents of the frame, or do you want a fixed predefined width?

Comment: yes, The frame should be adapt automatically to the contents of the frame.

Comment: sounds quite a lot like [mdframed: size frame to content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88634) and the links within....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth)  and [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)  packages.  First the `\BODY` of the environment is saved in a `\usebox` using the `varwidth` environment and then its width is measured to specify the `\userdefinewidth` of the `mdframed` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins. It is not needed in your actual use case.
- This is a slightly modified version of the solution at [mdframed: size frame to content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88634/mdframed-size-frame-to-content/164088#164088).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\TheoremWidthTweak}%

\NewEnviron{theorem}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\TheoremWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TheoremWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray,userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\TheoremWidthTweak\relax, #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[backgroundcolor=yellow!20]
    Sample
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[backgroundcolor=green!20]
    Somewhat longer text.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[backgroundcolor=orange!20]
    Much longer text that takes up more than one line. 
    This should span across the entire width of the page and continue on to the next line.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```