# mdframe size not matching table size

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I'm having some problems with the `mdframed` package in combination with `tabular`. After figuring out how to get the width of the frame to match the width of the object (a table in my case) using a hack described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164088/29192), there's not the same space from the table to the frame on either side.

[image]

It somehow seems there there is a bit more space on the left side, around 30%. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % den nemmeste måde at skrive kemiske navne
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % frame i images/figures
\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}%
\NewEnviron{MyMdframed}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        linecolor=red,
        linewidth=3pt,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyMdframed}
\begin{tabular}{l r}
    Trivialnavn & vanillin \\
    Sumformel & \ce{C8H8O3} \\
    Kemisk struktur & \ce{(CH3O)C6H3(OH)CHO} \\
    IUPAC & 4-hydroxy-3-methoxybenzaldehyde \\
    CAS nummer & 121-33-5 \\
    Farve & hvid-gullig \\
    Duft & behagelig, blomstret \\
    Molarmasse & \SI{152,15}{\gram\per\mole} \\
    Smeltepunkt & \SI{82}{\celsius} \\
    Kogepunkt & \SI{170}{\celsius} \\
    Kilde & Wolfram|Alpha \& Databogen
\end{tabular}
\end{MyMdframed}
\end{document}
```

Not exactly minimal, but you get the point. I figured it was something in relation to the way the width of the table is calculated, but I have no idea how to adjust it. I got the same problem when using plain `tikz` for the task as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88636/29192).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add two times the `linewidth` of the frame (here 3pt) to `userdefinedwidth`

```
userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak+6pt\relax,
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % den nemmeste måde at skrive kemiske navne
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % frame i images/figures
\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}%
\NewEnviron{MyMdframed}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        linecolor=red,
        linewidth=3pt,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak+6pt\relax,
        #1]
        \usebox0%
    \end{mdframed}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyMdframed}
\begin{tabular}{l r}
    Trivialnavn & vanillin \\
    Sumformel & \ce{C8H8O3} \\
    Kemisk struktur & \ce{(CH3O)C6H3(OH)CHO} \\
    IUPAC & 4-hydroxy-3-methoxybenzaldehyde \\
    CAS nummer & 121-33-5 \\
    Farve & hvid-gullig \\
    Duft & behagelig, blomstret \\
    Molarmasse & \SI{152,15}{\gram\per\mole} \\
    Smeltepunkt & \SI{82}{\celsius} \\
    Kogepunkt & \SI{170}{\celsius} \\
    Kilde & Wolfram|Alpha \& Databogen
\end{tabular}%
\end{MyMdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! (And for the edit as well).