# tikz setting font size to pts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I'm using tikz to create color boxes containing text. However I haven't been able to set font size within these boxes using pts.

I found a snippet [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84074/how-to-create-command-for-a-box-where-text-inside-the-box-can-automatically-adju/84123#84123) that defines a `Boxed` command:

```
\newcommand{\Boxed}[2][]{%
    % #1 = box draw/fill options
    % #2 = text
    \settowidth{\LengthOfText}{\mbox{#2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth}
        {\LengthOfText-\linewidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\TextWidth}{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth > 0pt ? \linewidth : \LengthOfText}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
            \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
            \node [text width=\TextWidth, #1] (Origin) {#2};
                (Origin.south west) rectangle (Origin.north east) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

I've modified it a little, however using a `tikzstyle` I'm only able to set font to things like `\small`, `\tiny`, etc. I would like to set font size to 10pt.

Comment: Probably it is more convenient to use the »[mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed)« package here.

Comment: Or even better `tcolorbox`.

Comment: I tried `mdframed` but I couldn't get it right either, what's wrong with using tikz? sorry I'm still a noob in Latex, thanks.

Comment: Nothing against using »[PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)«. But I would not try to reinvent the wheel but resort to a package that exactly covers the problem.

Comment: Don't think `Tikz` is relevant, check this question and associated answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/latex-specify-font-point-size

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the desired font size, since you don't mind the result in a box (which means no line or page breaking} is to just scale it by a factor of desired-point-size/document-point-size.

In this MWE, the document is 12pt, while I want the `\Boxed` in 10pt, so I use a `\scalebox` with a scale of 10/12 = 0.8333

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\LengthOfText}
\newlength{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth}
\newlength{\TextWidth}
\newcommand{\Boxed}[2][]{%
    % #1 = box draw/fill options
    % #2 = text
    \settowidth{\LengthOfText}{\mbox{#2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth}
        {\LengthOfText-\linewidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\TextWidth}{\LengthOfTextExceedingLineWidth > 0pt ? \linewidth : \LengthOfText}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
            \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
            \node [text width=\TextWidth, #1] (Origin) {#2};
                (Origin.south west) rectangle (Origin.north east) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
Normal text in 12pt font.  \scalebox{.8333}{\Boxed[blue]{10pt font}}
\end{document}
```

[image]